# How to send style attributes to child component

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I have component which implements input field:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="standard">
  <mat-label >{{label}}<span>*</span></mat-label>
  <input [type]="type"
  <span matSuffix>{{suffix}}</span>
</mat-form-field>
```

How can I send information about style attributes from parent component to child component? I would like to change font-weight of input and matSuffix value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I solved my own problem :) and I had to change only files of parent component. I've added (in @Component):

```
@Component({
  ....
  encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ParentComponent {
```

then in parent.html, in my child call:

```
<app-input-comp `class="add-bold-attribute"` ></app-input-comp>
```

and then in parent css file:

```
.add-bold-attribute input {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.add-bold-attribute span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```